# Android Full-screen issue

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm developing android App which is full-screen App,
in the main activity there are 2 buttons

**The issue is** when i click in the About button the pop-out activity appear 
after click on dismiss the title bar appear in the main activity, see the screen capture:

**The main activity** 
[image: The main activity]

**After clicking About button and clicking on dismiss**
[image: After clicking About button and clicking on dismiss]

about_popout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/about_shape"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12pt"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="It&apos;s a PopupWindow" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_dismiss"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="Dismiss"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ff5722"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.game.circle.thecirclegame.MainMenu">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To the Game"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
        android:layout_marginRight="100px"
        android:text="About"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.game.circle.thecirclegame">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GamePanel"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The class MainMenu.java where the title bar appears, **after clicking btn_about**

```
package com.game.circle.thecirclegame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_startGame, btn_about;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        addListinerToButtons();

    }

    public void addListinerToButtons(){

        btn_startGame = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        btn_about = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_about);


        btn_startGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,GamePanel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn_about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.about_popout, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                Button btn_dismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dismiss);

                btn_dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }});
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btn_about, 50, -30);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

i need to get red of the blue title bar.

Comment: do you NEVER want to show the titlebar?

Comment: Please post the Manifest. You likely have used an ActionBar theme on that activity (or you called `setToolbar` for some reason in the code)

Comment: And, by the way, nested LinearLayout are not recommended for performance reasons

Comment: @Akeshwar yes i do not want to show the title bar never

Comment: @cricket_007 both main activity and popout activity supposed to be full screen layout

Comment: That isn't what I asked... please [edit] with the requested files

Comment: yes sure @cricket_007

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Now the java code of the class where you see the toolbar, please?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes Boss,

Comment: It is not clear why you are using `PopupWindow` because that appears to be creating a whole new Activity-like interface. I think what you want is a `Dialog`

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe i am wrong, i need to display a window that have information about the developer i.e. about app. is it fine to use a dialog ?

Comment: I've seen apps that use Fragments, Dialogs, or Activities for an "About" view. If you point at a resource that tells you to use `PopupWindow`, then I could answer better

Comment: i may try to use dialog, no there is no resource it is just me trying to build the about popout layout in this way. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Because i didn't continue using the popup window,
i create a new activity instead and make the button redirect from main menu to About activity

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the title bar forever by calling:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before the `setContentView(R.layout.x)` in your activity class.

To make the app fullscreen, you can do:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Again, put  the above code before the `setContentView` method.

And make sure, if you are doing this, you should extend your Activity class by `Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity` or any other class.